# How correct update rpm if preremove.sh scipt run after postinstall.sh?

Tags: yum, upgrade, rpm

cat /etc/redhat-release

```
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
```

yum list yum

```
yum.noarch  3.4.3-154.el7.centos
```

Repo: https://github.com/patsevanton/simple-package-update

I build 1-th and 2-th version command

```
mvn clean package
```

When update 1-th version to 2-th

```
Running transaction
  Updating   : simple-package-update-1-2.noarch  1/2 

Run postinstall.sh
Run preremove.sh
  Cleanup    : simple-package-update-1-1.noarch  2/2 
  Verifying  : simple-package-update-1-2.noarch  1/2 
  Verifying  : simple-package-update-1-1.noarch  2/2 

Updated:
  simple-package-update.noarch 0:1-2
```

First

**Run postinstall.sh**

Second

**Run preremove.sh**

How correct update rpm if preremove.sh scipt run after postinstall.sh?

preremove.sh contain deregister service

postinstall.sh contain register service

Answer (score 0):

%preun scriptlet (in your case preremove.sh) is called when the package is being removed. This happens even during upgrade, because old package is being removed and new installed. You can check if it is upgrade or not using the value of `$1`. It is documented for example here https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Scriptlets

Comment: Can i user this construction?

https://pastebin.com/1LrCKzkY

Comment: `if [ $1 -gt 0 ] ; then preremove.sh` .....  This will be called when you are upgrading package (removing the old version).  When  you want to call it when the package is really being removed then  you have to `if [ $1 = 0 ] ; then`